# Laravel 9 with Vue 3. How to add list of css & js from template

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9

I install laravel 9 vue 3, But I don't know Where to list css & js properlly. can any one help me. I am trying for 2 days. but still stuck.

Don't know in vite.config.js or welcome.blade.php or else. Please help me guys

I tried in app.js, import in app.js but its not working